# Is there any way to easily convert .mat file to .nc file?

Tags: matlab, netcdf

Trying to convert data from a `.mat` file into a `.nc` file, so I can view the data quickly using NCVIEW.

The variable I want to save into a `.nc` file looks like this:

- Variable name: `Watts_Map`
- Variable description: `Wattages plotted over a set of geographic grid cells`
- Variable dimensions: `<225x61x2920 double>`

  So this would be a 3-D netCDF file.

The matrix is `225`x`61`, for each timestep. There are `2920` timesteps. Each grid cell contains a wattage value. So there are `2920` matrices of dimensions `225`x`61`.

- Longitude: `0W` to `140W`, `0.625 deg` resolution, denoted by `225`
- Latitude: `0N` to `30N`, `0.5 deg` resolution, denoted by `61`

There does not seem to be an intuitive way to do this. Trying `nccreate` and `ncwrite`.

Any advice on how to do this?

---

Here is the code I am trying:

```
% Clear out all data and clean up workspace

clc;
clear all;

% load the .mat file to be converted to netcdf file

%load('2000_ATL_Watts_Maps_inc_Land.mat');

% variable to be taken from .mat file and saved as netcdf file
% Watts_Map = W/sq m 
% Dimensions:  225x61x2920 (lon x lat x time)
% 
% Put another way, there are 2920 maps of size 225x61, containing W/sq m
% values for each grid cell
%
% Resolution:  longitude = 0.625 deg
%              latitude = 0.5 degree
%              time = starts at midnight on Jan 1st of the year, increments
%                     every 3 hours.  So timestep 1 is midnight on Jan 1st, 
%                     timestep 2 is 3am on Jan 1st, and so on.

% Create and write data to netcdf file

nccreate('test_files.nc','Watts','Dimensions',{'time' 2920 'lon' 225 'lat' 61});
```

Comment: Is using MATLAB or Python an option? Both can convert .mat files to .nc files.

Answer (score 1):

Hope this gets you started:

```
%% Create
!rm test_files.nc
nccreate('test_files.nc','Watts','Dimensions',{'time' 2920 'lon' 225 'lat' 61});
nccreate('test_files.nc','lat','Dimensions',{'lat' 61});
nccreate('test_files.nc','lon','Dimensions',{'lon' 225});
nccreate('test_files.nc','time','Dimensions',{'time' 2920});
ncdisp('test_files.nc');

%% write dimensions
% https://www.unidata.ucar.edu/software/netcdf/docs/netcdf/Dimensions.html

%Latitude: 0N to 30N, 0.5 deg resolution, denoted by 61
ncwrite('test_files.nc','lat',0:.5:30);
%Longitude: 0W to 140W, 0.625 deg resolution, denoted by 225
ncwrite('test_files.nc','lon',0:.625:140);
% Time?

%% write data
ncwrite('test_files.nc','Watts',rand(2920,225,61));
```

Comment: Thanks!  This helps a lot.  Now just have to figure out how to get the Watts to display properly (getting some error about min/max values in NCVIEW).