# How can I convert .mat file to a netCDF file?

Tags: matlab, netcdf, netcdf4

I have a .mat file with these variables in it. I have loaded it using `load` command.

1. lat: 129*1 double
2. lon: 135*1 double
3. var: 129*135*42369 double
4. start_date: '1901-01-01'
5. end_date: '2016-12-31'

I would like to create and export a netCDF file with the lat, long, and a daily time dimension. With the var as a variable.

## TRIED

```
>> ncid = netcdf.create('testing.nc','NC_WRITE');
>> %Define the dimensions
dimidt = netcdf.defDim(ncid,'time',length(start_date));
dimidlat = netcdf.defDim(ncid,'latitude',length(lat));
dimidlon = netcdf.defDim(ncid,'longitude',length(Lon));
>> %Define IDs for the dimension variables (pressure,time,latitude,...)
date_ID=netcdf.defVar(ncid,'time','double',[dimidt]);
latitude_ID=netcdf.defVar(ncid,'latitude','double',[dimidlat]);
longitude_ID=netcdf.defVar(ncid,'longitude','double',[dimidlon]);
>> precip_ID = netcdf.defVar(ncid,'var','double',[dimidt dimidlat dimidlon]);
>> netcdf.endDef(ncid);
>> netcdf.putVar(ncid,date_ID,0,830788,start_date:end_date);
netcdf.putVar(ncid,latitude_ID,0,830788,Lat);
netcdf.putVar(ncid,longitude_ID,0,830788,Lon);
```

## ERROR

```
Error using netcdflib
The number of elements implied by the count argument (830788) does not equal the number of data elements (2).

Error in netcdf.putVar (line 88)
netcdflib(funcstr,ncid,varid,varargin{:}
```

## OBJECTIVE

How can I export it to netCDF using MATLAB?

Comment: maybe this one can help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27025088/is-there-any-way-to-easily-convert-mat-file-to-nc-file

Comment: Thank you so much #ThomasIsCoding . It worked.

Comment: #ThomasIsCoding , can you please help me to write the time format while creating and writting netcdf file . As my date starts from 1901/01/01 and ends at 2016/12/31.  I have written remaining variables from the link as you referred. I am a beginner in the lab. Can you help me out?

Comment: sorry that actually I am not that familiar with netCDF, maybe you can set a bounty to attract more attraction from other experienced guys

Comment: Thank you so much #ThomasIsCoding